# To find the projection of $v = [14 ,11,-9 ]^t $ onto the subspace spanned by $u_1 = [1 ,4,-1]^t$ and $u_2 = [6 ,0,-4]^t$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

To find the projection of $v = [14 ,11,-9 ]^t $ onto the subspace spanned by $u_1 = [1 ,4,-1]^t$ and $u_2 = [6 ,0,-4]^t$.

Let $V$ be the subspace spanned by $u_1,u_2$ .

$proj_V(v) = proj_{u_1}(v) + proj_{u_2}(v)  = \frac{<v,u_1>}{<u_1,u_1>}u_1 + \frac{<v,u_2>}{<u_2,u_2>}u_2 = \frac{67}{18}u_1 + \frac{30}{13}u_2.$

Is the solution correct?

Comment: Are you talking about *orthogonal* projection here?

Comment: In order to directly add the projections, $u_1$ and $u_2$ must be orthogonal, but in this case, they are not

Comment: @ab123 Then how should I proceed??

Comment: @userly0 you need to find a pair of orthogonal vectors in the span of these 2 vectors; or even just find a vector in the span perpendicular to one of $u_1$ or $u_2$

Comment: You could instead do this by finding the projection onto the orthogonal complement of the subspace and subtracting that from $v$. Since you’re working in $\mathbb R^3$, this is particularly easy to do.